# Modifying variable references

Tags: python

I am new to coding in Python and I have a question about how variables store information. Suppose that:

1. I store some data D (an integer, list, dictionary, set, or string in my toy cases) into a variable x,
2. I set another variable y equal to x, and then
3. I modify the value of x to D'.

If I now retrieve the data in y, I would expect to get back one of D or D', but the answer I get seems to depend on the situation (and the type of D at the very least). I will illustrate with some examples below.

My questions is: under what conditions will I get D, and under what conditions will I get D'? I can see justifications for both possibilities -- what I want to understand is how to predict the outcome. Thank you for your help!

Case 1: If I run the code

```
x = 0
y = x
x = 1
print(y)
```

then the output is 0.

Case 2: If I run the code

```
x = [0]
y = x
x[0] = 1
print(y)
```

then the output is [1].

Case 3: If I run the code

```
x = {'key':0}
y = x
x['key'] = 1
print(y)
```

then the output is {'key' : 1}.

Case 4: If I run the code

```
x = set()
y = x
x.add(1)
print(y)
```

then the output is {1}.

Case 5: If I run the code

```
x = '0'
y = x
x += '1'
print(y)
```

then the output is 0.

So in cases 1 and 5, I am getting the original data stored in x, but in cases 2-4, I am getting the modified data stored in x. What is going on here? Why do I sometimes get the original data, and other times the modified data?

Comment: `x = 1` and `x[0] = 1` are *fundamentally different operations*, even though we use the word "assignment" to refer to both of them.  The first one rebinds a variable name, the second one mutates an existing object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Comment: Names in Python are just labels bound to objects - think tie-on labels. The object could be for example a value or a data structure holding values.  Labels can be moved to other objects and more than one label used on an object. See [Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for pointing this out. The syntax of the two expressions is very similar, but yes, I now see that in one case I am changing what the variable x refers to, and in the other I am changing the contents of the list [0].

Comment: @user19077881 I like this analogy a lot, and Batchelder's article was really helpful. Thanks for straightening out my mental model for variable assignment -- everything more or less fell into place once I got this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 1 and 5 you set y to reference the value that x was holding, then you changed the value that x was holding but y is still pointing at its original value.   In the other cases (2-4) you did not modify what x was referencing (the set, list or dictionary.  In those cases you modified the contents of the object, but did not change what x referred to.

Answer (score 2):

In all cases, the line `y = x` make `y` and `x` refer to the same object.  And if you were to do `y = z` then `y` would not refer to the `x` object anymore.

If `x` is a mutable object, such as a list, dictionary, or set, you can modify that object and you'll see the change to both.

If `x` is an immutable object such as a number or string, it won't be modified - it will be replaced.  So `y` will refer to the former object, and `x` will refer to something new.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, @Mark Ransom. I also found your answer at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference) very helpful while I was trying understand the examples above!

Comment: Best answer to this question I think. Thanks Mark!